# PHP option tag and array

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-select

Just working on a small University project to develop an e-commerce website. I have been provided some code and I am altering this to my needs.

I currently have a problem with getting some arrays to work within an option and select tag. The difference being each of these arrays has an action associated with it eg, moving onto another page.

The problem seems to be this action is not being used within the option tags. As seen here http://mkiddr.com/phptests/shopping/

Here is my original code before editing:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <p><a href="index.php">Home</a> | Browse:
    <?php
        $q="SELECT c_id, c_name FROM sc_cat";
        $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            echo "<a href='category.php?id=$row[0]'>$row[1]</a> ";
        }
        unset($q); //unset query variable
        mysqli_free_result($result); //free result
        ?>
</div>
<div id="content"><!-- note this is an opening tag -->
```

Here is my code edited (doesn't work)

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <p><a href="index.php">Home</a> | Browse:

    <select>
    <?php
        $q="SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM ProductCategories";
        $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conn'],$q);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

            echo "<option value='category.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></option>";
            //display categories

            }
        unset($q); //unset query variable
        mysqli_free_result($result); //free result
    ?>
    </select>

</div>
<div id="content"><!-- note this is an opening tag -->
```

Would really appreciate if someone could give us a hand with this!

Comment: You have an extraneous `</a>` before `</option>`.

Comment: Even though this is just a university project be wary about sql injection. Use parametrized procedures. I just ran this and got a list of all your products `http://mkiddr.com/phptests/shopping/category.php?id=1 or 1=1`. I could have easily run something like this `http://mkiddr.com/phptests/shopping/category.php?id=1;DROP TABLE ProductCategories;--` and ruined all your hard work. See http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @Matt Kidd Uhm, why was Simon's answer been chosed as correct - you're using my solution, as far as I can see

Comment: Much appreciated Kevin. This is actually part of my criteria, I'm just focussing on getting everything together to begin with. You have however certainly saved me time looking for weaknesses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that option tag has no "action" to execute. You must use javascript to redirect user to selected option. Change SELECT tag to

```
<select onchange="window.location = this.value;">
```

Comment: excellent seems to have done the trick to some extent... As you'll see mkiddr.com/phptests/shopping when selecting Mens_Accessories it'll take you to the correct category however the select will not display the correct title. The first category also seems to be unresponsive. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: Sure, just change echo "<option value='category.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></option>"; to $selected = ($row[0] == $_GET['id']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; echo "<option $selected value='category.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></option>";

Comment: Fantastic! that's excellent, much appreciated. Coding is not my thing! although I'm starting to get the hang of things...

Answer (score -1):

try swopping out your while loop for the following:

```
   while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

        echo "<option value='category.php?id=".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</a></option>";
        //display categories

        }
```

And see if this should work

As @Stormherz mentions also to have this load automatically on selection you need to place the onclick method to the option on the select tag;

Comment: What's the difference? You just switched from functional to OO interface, but they're equivalent.

Comment: excellent seems to have done the trick to some extent... 

As you'll see http://mkiddr.com/phptests/shopping/ when selecting Mens_Accessories it'll take you to the correct category however the select will not display the correct title. The first category also seems to be unresponsive. 

Any idea why this may be?

Comment: the first one is not responsive as its already on the value so there is no change event you will need to add another option at the front like <option value="">Select</option> but leave this outside the loop

Comment: What do you mean select will not display the correct title, do you mean the options in the drop down? And is this before you press select or after on the next page

Comment: Fantastic, Once again much appreciated. I feel daft that I didn't see this! All sorted :)